# Are string functions like strlen, strcpy, strcat really old and bad?

Tags: c++

I asked a question about this topic and people say that there is something wrong with my university for teaching me these ancient library. Is it really true and what should I be using instead? Sorry I am still quite new I am in the first year.

Comment: They should not be used in c++. The standard library class `std::string` replaces these operations, which are more or less plain c. The standard library preserves these with the[ `<cstring>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) header, for compatibility.

Comment: The library you are talking about is the C string library. Your universitry should be teaching your about C++ strings not C strings. But as we often see here, many colleges do teach old fashioned C++.

Comment: @john: "do teach old fashioned C++" That is not old fashioned C++. It is using C with a c++ compiler, maybe using the keyword `class` somewhere but still ignoring all C++ principals. No OOP, no ownership, no abstraction, data and functions always separated. We have the same problem here in Germany. The classes more or less teaching nonsense. And if we get these people, they wonder why we can't hire them. We prefer hobbyist in programming, which have studied some other fundamental courses but using computers as a tool and not study the tool itself.

Comment: The functions functions you're talking about were invented very early in the development of the C language, before C++ existed.  They are fine (still) *if you are writing in C*, but C++ is a different language.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No, a lot of these functions were never fine! Most of them have a lot of especially security problems. A lot of tools marking these old c style functions as errors and the use is forbidden in a lot of environments. Most of these functions have a "better" replacement with a different signature. strcpy - > strncpy only for example!

Comment: For an opinion on this topic which might explain where that came from, see this talk: [Stop teaching C in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: Sorry, @Klaus, but I beg to differ. One can object to working directly with C strings *at all* (at least in C++), but if one is going to work with them then the standard functions for doing so are not particularly worse than the other alternatives.  One has to pay careful attention to buffer sizes and string lengths no matter which raw-string functions one uses.  As for `strncpy` in particular, it is decidedly *un*safe, because its alternative to overrunning the destination buffer is to leave it unterminated.  That can produce worse results in practice than `strcpy`.

Answer (score 6):

Raw C strings are responsible for a significant percentage of security flaws in real world software.

Properly handling buffers is hard, and getting it wrong is depressingly common.  There is a use for low level raw memory buffer manipulation of strings, but teaching it first is questionable.

One way of teaching C++ is to teach it as C, then add on some C++ features.  Another is to teach it first as C++, and then add on the C compatible sub dialect.

The criticism you are hearing is objecting to the teach C then C++ option.

Learning how to program in C is great; trying to learn both C and C++ at the same time makes you a bad C and bad C++ programmer.

When C++ was first invented, this was a reasonable way to do it.  There were C experts but no C++ experts.  It has been a few decades since then, and best practices in C++ are no longer that similar to best practices in C, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what they do is useful since you may encounter ancient code that uses them.

But no, there is no need to use them in modern C++. By modern, I mean something that is being written now or has been written during this millennium.

One of the functions you mentioned, `std::strlen` is fairly OK to use. Technically you dont need it, but neither is it terribly bad to use.

> what should I be using instead?

Most of the time: std::string and std::string_view and their member functions.